# why it isn't possible to sort a std::map directly using std::sort based upon its value field

Tags: c++

I've already seen lot of solutions for sorting a std::map based on its value. But I want to know why it's not possible to sort it directly using std::sort like the code I've written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


void print_values(const std::map<size_t, size_t>& map_data) {
    for(const auto& my_pair : map_data)
        std::cout << my_pair.first << " : " << my_pair.second << "\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

bool compare(const std::pair<size_t, size_t>& a, const std::pair<size_t, size_t>& b) {
    return a.second > b.second;
}

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<size_t, size_t> coins_count;
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(1, 2));
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(2, 3));
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(3, 4));
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(4, 2));
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(5, 3));
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(6, 1));
    coins_count.insert(std::make_pair(7, 2));
    
    print_values(coins_count);
    
    std::sort(coins_count.begin(), coins_count.end(), compare);
    
    print_values(coins_count);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `std::sort` orders elements in-place, changing the original container, but `std::map` is already sorted by keys, you cannot change that ordering.

Comment: First, you cannot sort a map with `std::sort` whether you are trying to sort by value or otherwise. You can provide alternative sorting for a map, but it has to be determined at compile time. Second, you can never sort a map by value, even with a custom comparator.

Comment: It may help to understand that an `std::map`'s keys are `const`. It is not possible to change an existing element's key.

Comment: In addition to the other good reasons, `std::sort` requires random-access iterators but `std::map` only provides bidirectional iterators.

Comment: Guys. The comments section is not for answers. This isn't hard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map itself is always sorted by key. So you can only sort some other thing, that could refer to map elements.

You could sort an array of map iterators:

```
std::vector<decltype(coins_count)::iterator> vec;
for (auto i = coins_count.begin(), end = coins_count.end(); i != end; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(i);
}
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [](auto& a, auto& b) { return a->second < b->second; }
);    
for(auto&& i : vec) {
    std::cout << i->first << " : " << i->second << "\n";
}
```

Alternatively you could sort an array of map keys:

```
std::vector<decltype(coins_count)::key_type> vec;
for(auto&& i : coins_count) {
    vec.push_back(i.first);
}
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [&coins_count](auto& a, auto& b) {
        return coins_count.at(a) < coins_count.at(b);
    }
);
for(auto&& i : vec) {
    std::cout << i << " : " << coins_count.at(i) << "\n";
}
```

Code will output:

```
6 : 1
1 : 2
4 : 2
7 : 2
2 : 3
5 : 3
3 : 4
```

Comment: does the statement `for(auto&& i : coins_count)` move the map pair into `i`(rvalue). If so, doesn't it get deleted from `coins_count` ?

Comment: `move the map pair` There is move? I do not think anything is moved. The type is deduced to `iterator&` I think (so a reference is moved, as much). [Forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references)

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` is implemented as some flavor of binary search tree sorted by key.  That means that a `std::map` must always be sorted by key, using the comparison function defined for the map at construction time, for element lookup to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a map are always maintained in a sorted manner, by definition.

You can define this ordering yourself using a template argument, but you cannot manually change the order of elements yourself with `std::sort` (and this call will fail even if no elements would have been swapped).