# Change output order from vector and my map c++

Tags: c++

I am new to coding in c++ and need help now. I have made this program that reads how many times a word occurs in a text file and then print it. But my probmlem is that I want the word which occurs most in the top of the list produced by `cout`, now the word "the" is printed last but I want it to be first in the list and so on.

[The output of the code below is listed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocLhg.png)

This is my `main` function:

```
std::map<std::string,int> words;
std::ifstream input("text.txt");

std::string s;
std::string empty ="";
while((s=getNextToken(input))!=empty )
        ++words[s];

//copy pairs to vector
vector<pair<string,int> > wordvector;
copy(words.begin(), words.end(), back_inserter(wordvector));

//sort the vector by second (value) instead of key
sort(wordvector.begin(), wordvector.end(), val_lt);

for(int i=0; i<wordvector.size(); ++i)
    cout << wordvector[i].first << " = " << wordvector[i].second << endl;

return 0;
```

Function `Getnexttoken()`

```
std::string getNextToken(std::istream &in)

char c;
std::string ans="";
c=in.get();
while(!std::isalpha(c) && !in.eof())//cleaning non letter charachters

    c=in.get();

while(std::isalpha(c))

    ans.push_back(std::tolower(c));
    c=in.get();

return ans;
```

Struct `val_lt`

```
struct val_lessthan : binary_function < pair<string,int>, pair<string,int>, bool >
bool operator() (const pair<string,int>& x, const pair<string,int>& y) const
{return x.second<y.second;}
}val_lt;
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617780/why-it-isnt-possible-to-sort-a-stdmap-directly-using-stdsort-based-upon-its/63618354?noredirect=1#comment112504466_63618354

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead, provide [mcve] as text in your question.

Comment: And the simplest solution to your problem would be just printing in reverse... Or you can change your sorting function (which you decided to not show to us).

Comment: @Harry OP sorts a vector, which is a copy of the map, not the map itself.

Comment: It would be probably good if OP could add the explicit form of the comparator val_lt they pass as an argument in the sort method. I suspect ordering the vector by value with a greater_than would actually solve their issue.

Comment: What is your `val_lt`?

Comment: braces in code has been lost :). I see this third time in question on SO (different users). I wonder why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible solutions to your issue. (i) Using a (reverse)  loop or iterator to go through the final vector, end to start, (ii) directly sorting from largest to smallest (I suppose `val_lt` does a "less than" comparison, so you want to use a "greater than"...) .

Easiest change to your code would just be to reverse the for loop:

```
for (int i = wordvector.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
[...]
```